# "command not found: create-next-app" how do I create a next application?

Tags: next.js

I am new to Next.js I am using this command to create my app:

```
npx create-next-app
```

but it is giving an error which is:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\danyyal'
> command not found: create-next-app

how to create the app? p.s I have nodejs installed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First install `create-next-app` globally by doing

```
npm i -g create-next-app
```

After you can use `create-next-app` CLI to create next app.

If you want to create new next app in current directory do

```
create-next-app .
```

For a named next app just do

```
create-next-app your-app-name
```

Comment: I've tried your way of doing but I'm getting an error Message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947874/next-js-installation-error-npm-warn-tarball       PLease have a look

Answer (score 11):

Firstly create it manually with:

```
npm install react next react-router
```

Try to install the create-next-app package:

```
npm i create-next-app
```

Then you can do again:

```
npx create-next-app my-awesome-app
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always setup the project manually.

Step 1 :
Install next, react and react-dom in your project:

```
npm install next react react-dom
```

Step 2 :
Open package.json and add the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}
```

Step 3: Populate ./pages/index.js with the following contents:

```
function HomePage() {
  return <div>Welcome to Next.js!</div>
}

export default HomePage
```

To start developing your application run `npm run dev or yarn dev`. This starts the development server on http://localhost:3000.

**UPDATE**

Since you needed more help.

Create a new folder and name it as you like,then open your terminal & go into the project folder and run the step 1 commands. Now open package.json file and inside that write the step 2 code. Now create pages folder inside the current project directory and inside that create a index.js file and write the step 3 code. Now run the project by doing npm run dev.
So the project structure will be like this.

```
--Nextjs Project
     ---pages
           |--- index.js
     ---packages.json
```

Comment: hey I am a newbie and I don't know how to do it manually can you explain? should I create an empty folder and run the command in step 1 or how should I?

Comment: Create a new folder and name it as you like,then open your terminal &go into the project folder and run the step 1 commands. Now create a package.json file and inside that write the step 2 code. Now create pages folder inside the current project directory and inside that create a index.js file and write the step 3 code. Now run the project by doing npm run dev. Will update the answer to help you out

Answer (score 2):

You can create it manually by creating a folder and run `npm init` to create a package.json file the run `npm install next react react-dom --save`, Open the package.json and add this

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow thanks for contributing, you can use `code block` for `code section`, `json`, etc,.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `npm i create-next-app` first.

Answer (score 1):

You must use node 10.13 or later to make it work !

[NextJS Requirements](https://nextjs.org/docs#system-requirements)

`1. nvm use 10`

`2. npx create-next-app`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it globally first, using the command
**npm install -g create-react-app**

And then, you can create your app using the command,
***npx create-react-app***

Answer (score 0):

First, install npx globally (if not)

> npm i -g npx

Then, run command create-next-app

> npm i create-next-app

then you will be able to create-next-app by running

> npx create-next-app appname

Answer (score 0):

first installed npx globally using `-g`
`npx i -g npx`

then installed
`npm i -g create-next-app`