# Next JS Installation Error: (npm WARN tarball )

Tags: npm, error-handling, terminal, next.js, npx

I got an error while installing `Next js`

My Node Version: Latest **16.13.0** .
I've tried downgrading the node version. but it can't help

**Directory** : `E:\Main\project`

Now, When I execute `npx create-next-app .` in my terminal.

I got the following error Message:

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for whatwg-url@https://registry.npmjs.org/whatwg-url/-/whatwg-url-7.1.0.tgz (sha512-WUu7Rg1DroM7oQvGWfOiAK21n74Gg+T4elXEQYkOhtyLeWiJFoOGLXPKI/9gzIie9CtwVLm8wtw6YJdKyxSjeg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for whatwg-url@https://registry.npmjs.org/whatwg-url/-/whatwg-url-7.1.0.tgz (sha512-WUu7Rg1DroM7oQvGWfOiAK21n74Gg+T4elXEQYkOhtyLeWiJFoOGLXPKI/9gzIie9CtwVLm8wtw6YJdKyxSjeg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Divyanshu sah\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\59\4b\bb460d43ae833ba10bc659f3a200adb59fbe0683e4f87a55c441890e86dc8b7968891683862d73ca23ff60cc889ef42b7054b9bcc2dc3a60974acb14a37a
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Divyanshu sah\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\59\4b\bb460d43ae833ba10bc659f3a200adb59fbe0683e4f87a55c441890e86dc8b7968891683862d73ca23ff60cc889ef42b7054b9bcc2dc3a60974acb14a37a'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Divyanshu sah\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-12T18_38_56_606Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save-exact --save react react-dom next has failed.
```

**NOTE:** I've also tried like this: `npx create-next-app demo` but getting the same error message

What should I do now ?